# Refreshing Ribbon in CRM on home screen (no entity form open)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon-control

On my home screen, I have a button for Login and a button for Logout. Initially, the button Login is Enabled and Logout is disabled. On click of Login button, i make an AJAX call and login the user to a system. Now, on this, i want the Logout button to be clickable and want to grayout the Login button. I have a corresponding javascript written. However, i want to refresh the Ribbon button. How do i do that?

when i try Xrm.Page.ui.refreshRibbon, it breaks saying refreshRibbon is invalid. When i tried watching Xrm.Page.ui.. it returns NULL.

Comment: try using `crmGrid.Refresh();` or `window.refreshRibbon();`

Comment: i tried window.refreshRibbon().. it returned undefined.. i will try crmGrid.Refresh() now.. just fyi.. i am workin on CRM-2011

Comment: if `window.refreshRibbon()` returns undefined, then it is running fine. It has no return value. try using it in your code

Comment: hey.. you are right! it worked.. i actually had been trying it from Developer tools from Watch window.. and i took a chance and put it in my ccode and executed it! it worked just fine.. though, i am now facing another issue that the Enable rule is getting only applied on one button while it is assocaited with two buttons.. i will let you know how is this working

Comment: glad it helped, mark my answer as accepted to help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are already in the `XRM Ribbon Context` so you can use the `XRM Ribbon` Related functions directly in the Ribbon button's JS.

try

```
window.refreshRibbon()
```